# Programmatically Record a call and save file in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7

We have complete an application in iPhone.But there is this requirement to record a call and when call completed then have to save the file in iPhone.I know iPhone do not allow this .But we don't want this App to upload on App store.It is for limited users only.Can this task is feasible pro grammatically.